# Initializing a date within custom class results in error: "instance member cannot be used on type"

Tags: ios, swift, date

I found a few other questions, but none of the solutions worked, maybe my case is different in some critical aspect. Here's the code:

```
class ToDoList {

    let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components([.Day , .Month , .Year], fromDate: date)

    let dateCreated : Int = components.year*10_000 + components.month*100 + components.day  //TD: take YYYYMMDD from NSDate each initialization
    ...
}
```

XCode Error:

> "Instance member 'calendar' cannot be used on type 'ToDoList'.

I have tried implementing components as a variable with a getter instead, to no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

class ToDoList {

```
let dateCreated : Int

init(){
    let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components([.Day , .Month , .Year], fromDate: date)

    dateCreated = components.year*10_000 + components.month*100 + components.day  //TD: take YYYYMMDD from NSDate each initialization }
    // do other stuff .....
```

}

}

I solved it by declaring dateCreated outside the init() function and then initializing it inside the init() function.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare a property or instance variable on the top level of a class depending on values of other instance variables.

You could use a computed property

```
class ToDoList {

  var dateCreated : Int {
    let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components([.Day , .Month , .Year], fromDate: date)
    return components.year * 10_000 + components.month * 100 + components.day
  }

}
```

or a lazy instantiated variable

```
class ToDoList {

  lazy var dateCreated : Int = {
    let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = components([.Day , .Month , .Year], fromDate: date)
    return components.year * 10_000 + components.month * 100 + components.day
  }()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare computed property:

```
var components : NSDateComponents {
   get {
      return calendar.components([.Day , .Month , .Year], fromDate: date)
   }
}
```

Please note that it will be `var` instead of `let`. But as far as you don't have setter this value will be constant.